# FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: After migrating wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, database-migration, easy-engine

I just migrate my old site from another vps to the new one. New vps is running easyengine v3.8 on a fresh debian 8 instalation.

The migration  is done via rsync command. The steps of migration process are :

1. Create new wordpress site in new vps
2. Pointing DNS to new IP, new site running well.
3. Remove all wordpress files in /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs
4. Dump mydomain.com's database in old vps
5. Migrating data ( including dumped database ) from old vps to new vps via rsync
6. Import database in new vps.
7. Edit wp-config.php

Unfortenately, my new site wasn't live at all. Instead, it gives a HTTP 500 error with blank white screen. Even after i enable WP_DEBUG, the screen still white with no message on it.

I've tried to deactivate all plugins, still no change. Then i look to error log ini /var/www/mydomain.com/logs/error.log, it show message like this :

```
2019/01/16 01:03:37 [error] 8811#0: *849 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0  

PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/mydomain.com/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 167.248.155.196, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mydomain.com"
```

From this message, I notice there is a different webroot location, old webroot is located under /var/www/html/mydomain.com , while new webroot is located under /var/www/mydomain/htdocs.

is there any suggest? Thank you.